# How to redirect to a link using selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Hi I want to redirect to a link but I want to save the cookies too

is there any way to save cookies and redirect to a URL

```
required_url = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='main-content']/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a").get_attribute("href")
```

this required_url has a link and I want to redirect to this link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For saving cookies, Use pickle as following.

```
import pickle
import selenium.webdriver

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.example.com")
pickle.dump( driver.get_cookies() , open("cookies.pkl","wb"))
```

And later to add them back:

```
import pickle
import selenium.webdriver

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.example.com")
cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))
for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
```

and for redirecting to another URL

```
required_url = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='main-content']/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a").get_attribute("href")
driver.get(required_url)
```